# M2: estimate shipping method error

Tags: magento2, shipping-methods

I'm having a really weird trouble with my extension, as the shipping method section in checkout cannot be loaded, here's what it shows in inspect element:

[image]

so the above POST request cannot be loaded and now I don't know where to dig into to fix this. Any idea what the cause is for this problem? thank you

Answer (score 0):

Enable error reporting in php (for example uncomment #ini_set('display_errors', 1); in app/bootstrap.php) and see response of this post.
Then enable debugging with xdebug and add breakpoint in place of error and continue debug.

Comment: I think thats a js error, I don't really know where to put my breakpoint

Answer (score 0):

This error is caused by many situations, so you either provide us with what the php apache error_log or the reporting from php as @KAndy mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

In my case turning to "No" "Use Web Server Rewrites" made it work by adding "index.php/" before "/rest/default/V1..."

Comment: I tried this on my test system, broke my local. Be advised if anyone stumbles across this

Answer (score 0):

**Run below commands**

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
php bin/magento c:c
chmod -R 777 var/ generated/ pub/
```